# Convertir cada palabra de frase en elemento de lista me da error y el segundo codigo para hacer esto no lo entiendo

Tags: python

```
#Primer codigo quiero que me digan por que me da error
def toslice(s):
    result = ""
    final = []
    for c in s:
        if c == "":
            return result
            final += [result]
        else:
            result += c
    return final

#Segundo codigo expliquenmelo por favor
def head(s): 
    result = "" 
    for letter in s: 
         if letter == " ": 
            return result 
        else: 
            result = result + letter 
    return result

def tail(s): 
    if " " not in s: 
        return "" 
    i = s.index(" ") 
    return s[i+1:]

def toSlice(s):
    result = [] 
    hd = head(s) 
    tl =tail(s) 
    while hd != "": 
        result = result + [hd] 
        hd = head(tl) 
        tl = tail(tl) 
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

### Cómo separar una frase en palabras

No necesitas realmente implementar nada, porque Python ya trae una función que lo hace:

```
frase = "Esto es una prueba"
lista = frase.split()
```

El resultado en `lista` es:

```
['Esto', 'es', 'una', 'prueba']
```

## Qué estaba mal en tu código

Tu código tiene varias cosas mal:

```
#Primer codigo quiero que me digan por que me da error
def toslice(s):
    result = ""
    final = []
    for c in s:
        if c == "":
            return result
            final += [result]
        else:
            result += c
    return final
```

`for c in s` te va devolviendo cada letra de `c`. Hasta ahí vamos bien.

`if c == ""` compara una letra con la cadena vacía. Eso no va a ocurrir nunca. Cada letra de la cadena original es distinta de la cadena vacía. Supongamos que querías comparar en cambio con el espacio: `if c == " "`, eso sí será cierto en cuanto aparezca el primer espacio y falso si no. Vamos primero al caso falso. En caso falso haces `result+=c`, lo que añade la letra que has encontrado a la cadena `result`.

Cuando encuentres el primer espacio, el `if c == " "` será cierto, y entonces haces `return result`. La cadena `result` contiene por tanto la primera palabra hasta el primer espacio.

Depués tienes la instrucción `final += [result]`, pero esta instrucción no llegará a ejecutarse nunca, pues ya acabas de hacer un `return`.

El `return final` que tienes en la última línea tampoco llega a ejecutarse nunca en el momento que encuentres un espacio (pues retorna antes), pero si no encuentras ningún espacio sí que llegarás a ese punto, y retornarás la variable `final`. Ahora bien, esa variable contiene una lista vacía pues nunca hemos llegado a meter nada en ella.

No está claro si pretendes que la función retorne la primera palabra hasta el primer espacio, o una lista con todas las palabras. En cualquier caso a la vista de lo anterior, tienes ya ingredientes para intentar de nuevo por tí mismo hallar una solución. Si te encuentras en dificultades pregunta de nuevo.

### Cómo funciona el otro código

- La función `head()` es muy similar a lo que intentaba hacer tu código, pues va mirando letra a letra y si no es un espacio, lo va concatenando a `result`, hasta encontrar el primer espacio en cuyo caso retorna `result` (que contendrá por tanto la primera palabra). Importante, si no encuentra ningún espacio acabará por salir del bucle y se encontrará con otro `return result`, y en ese momento la cadena `result` contendrá una copia completa de la cadena original. De este modo funciona también si la cadena original no tenía espacios.
- La función `tail()` retorna todo lo que haya tras el primer espacio, pero usando otra técnica. Primero comprueba si el espacio forma parte de la cadena, con `if " " not in s`. Si no hay espacios en la cadena, decide retornar la cadena vacía (tiene sentido pues en ese caso la cadena de entrada es una sola palabra y no hay nada tras ella). De otro modo usa `s.index(" ")` para encontrar la posición del primer espacio y un *slice* `s[i+1:]` para extraer todo lo que haya desde la posición `i+1` hasta el final. Es decir, todo lo que hay tras el primer espacio.
- Finalmente la función `toSlice()` hace uso de las dos anteriores para ir partiendo la cadena por los espacios. Primero usa `head()` para extraer la primera palabra, y luego usa `tail()` para extraer todo lo que haya tras la primera palabra. El resultado de `head()` lo añade a la lista `result`, y el resultado de `tail` es la nueva cadena sobre la que vuelve a hacer lo mismo, una y otra vez, mientras `head()` le devuelva algo. Fíjate que llegará un momento, al final de la cadena cuando ya sólo quede una palabra, en que `head()` retornará esa palabra, mientras que `tail()` retornará la cadena vacía. Cuando en la siguiente iteración se intente aplicar `head()` sobre esa cadena vacía, tendremos otra vez una cadena vacía y así se saldrá del bucle.

Mi opinión es que esta segunda forma es bastante retorcida e inefeiciente. Ibas mejor por tu camino salvo por los errores señalados. Y en todo caso, la solución más eficiente y corta en la práctica es usar el `split()` que puse al principio.